# How to bypass 'noglob' for 'which' in zsh?

Tags: zsh, alias, which

I want to use the `which` command to see which executable is actually being invoked, but the defensive `noglob` aliases keep getting in the way.

Is there a shortcut that I can use to find which executable is invoked when the command is aliased ?

I am using the `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `which -a COMMAND` (or `where COMMAND` or `whence -ca COMMAND`) to find all occurences of `COMMAND` in the command path.

For example:

```
% alias ls='noglob ls'
% ls () /bin/ls
% which ls
ls: aliased to noglob ls
% which -a ls
ls: aliased to noglob ls
ls () {
        /bin/ls
}
/bin/ls
```

As aliases are replaced in the command line before anything is executed, the second command in the list is the one you are looking for (assuming of course that the first line is somehow aliased to the same name)

Comment: Can you please explain why does it work? There is no man entry for `where` or `whence`.

Comment: In *zsh* `which`, `where` and `whence` are all built-in commands, with `which` being equivalent to `whence -c` and `where` being equivalent to `whence -ca`. Their documentation can be found in `man zshbuiltins`. While there is a manpage for `which`, it is not for the built-in, but for the external command (usually `/bin/which` or `/usr/bin/which`). See also the output of the command `which -a which`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `which -p` e.g.:

```
✗ which ls
ls: aliased to ls --color=tty
✗ which -p ls
/bin/ls
```

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins:

(whence) -p

Do a path search for name even if it is an alias, reserved word, shell function or builtin.